# How to draw SoftKeyboard keyCodes on a SurfaceView?

Tags: android

I have a problem with the softkeyboard and the surfaceview. I want to write text on the surfaceview throught the onDraw method when I type in the soft keyboard. I get the event but I couldn't get the corresponding character to draw. I see a lot of post, and in someone it say that the getNumber() should respond with the corresponding character but it fail with badcodes.
Here is may onKey method:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "keyCode: "+keyCode+" - " + event.getNumber()+" Un: "+event.getUnicodeChar());
        this.charToDraw = ""+event.getNumber();
        this.forceOnDraw();
        return false;
    }
```

The DDMS show this:

```
01-18 16:35:27.440: DEBUG/xxxxxxx(6227): keyCode: 47 - �� Un: 115
01-18 16:35:27.440: DEBUG/xxxxxxx(6227): onDraw: WRITING:��
```

I also try to use:

```
char keyCode = (char)keyCode;
String keyCode = "" + keyCode;
```

but get the same result.

I need to transform the keyCode to a string to display with the drawString of the surfaceview canvas.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
event.getDisplayLabel()
```

inside your onKey() method.